# How do I set quotaUser on a DetectDocumentText call in C#?

Tags: c#, google-api-dotnet-client, google-cloud-vision

I'm using the Google Vision API in C#. I want to set a quota on the number of calls I make on behalf of a user. The documentation says to use the `quotaUser` parameter in the request. However, I can't figure out where I can specify `quotaUser in the C# API.
https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage

I've looked at the generic API documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage

This is the working code I have, which I'd like to modify to pass in a `quotaUser` value:

```cs
var cred = Credentials.CreateScoped(ImageAnnotatorClient.DefaultScopes);
var channel = new Channel(ImageAnnotatorClient.DefaultEndpoint.ToString(), cred.ToChannelCredentials());
var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create(channel);
var image = Image.FromBytes(bytes);
var annotations = Client.DetectDocumentText(image);
```

How can I modify this code to pass in a `quotaUser` parameter?

Comment: The `quotaUser` parameter is specified in terms of the REST API rather than the gRPC API that the Google.Cloud.Vision.V1 package uses. I'm asking internally for an equivalent - I think I know what it might be, but I want to check before saying.

Comment: @JonSkeet If there's no way to do it using the gRPC API, do you know of some example C# code that would show how to translate what I have into the REST API?

Comment: I don't know of any samples for the REST API specifically for Vision. You'd want to use Google.Apis.Vision.v1, creating a VisionService and calling service.Images.Annotate with a batch request. See https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Vision.v1/latest/api/Google.Apis.Vision.v1.VisionService.html for docs - if you have trouble making progress, I can create a full sample, but I don't have time to do that *right now*. Happy to help more if you need it though.